# React pass props when child component is a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-props

How can I pass props to a child component when the component is a variable.  In the following code, I need to pass the prev function as a prop to the step.  Thanks.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Wizard = (props)=>{
    const [step] = useState(0);
    const CurrStep = props.steps[step];

    const prev = ()=>{
        console.log('prev called')
    }

    return (
        <div>   
            {// need to pass prev as a prop to the CurrStep component}
            {CurrStep }
        </div>)
}

export default Wizard

Wizard.propTypes = {
  header: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  steps: PropTypes.array.isRequired,//array of functional components 
  wizardContext: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onComplete: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: What type is `CurrStep`? Is it a function/component class or is it a rendered component? Can you include the code that defines `props.steps`?

Comment: Hi, it is an array of functional components.  I added proptypes.

Comment: What are the props on `CurrStep`?

Comment: not sure what you mean.  steps is an array of components.  I want to render one of them and pass in props, without knowing the exact name of the component.

Comment: If steps components are taking only one prop, i.e. prev then good otherwise [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can spread `props` inside the `CurrStep` component like this

```
return <CurrStep {...props} />;
```

here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-kowalevski-yh4qn?file=/src/App.js:0-438) demo of the code below

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Wizard = props => {
  const [step] = useState(0);

  const Comp1 = props => <div>{props.a}</div>;
  const Comp2 = props => <div>{props.a}</div>;
  const comps = [Comp1, Comp2];
  const CurrStep = comps[step];

  // this is just for demo, you can just pass props straight from Wizard
  props = { a: "a", ...props };
  return <CurrStep {...props} />;
};

export default Wizard;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// adding (props) =>
const CurrStep = (...props) => props.steps[step](...props);

const prev = () => {
    console.log('prev called')
}

return (
    <div>
       {CurrStep(prev)}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to pass the props.  I log props in CurrStep and it is an empty object.

Comment: doesn't compile, I get TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.  Probably referring to props.steps

Comment: seems so, it is the only occurrence of `0` at the code... isn't it array hold functional components?

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake, I was passing in an array like this:

[, ] instead of

[Step1, Step2]

Sorry to waste your time.